# Visual Studio C# Keydown blocking each other

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to make two keydowns working at the same time, so they don't block each other?

```
    private void multiplayer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is only one UI thread.  enqueue you work to happen on a background thread and you should be go.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be running into an issue with key repeat.  If that is the case the down will only fire for the last key pressed.  What you need to do instead is control the state with KeyDown, KeyUp, and Deactivate as well as have a timer which will do the actual work.  The timer will control how fast your "game loop" runs... for my example I just enabled the timer and set the interval to 10.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool _k1 = false;
    private bool _k2 = false;

    private bool _d1 = false;
    private bool _d2 = false;

    private int _u1 = 0;
    private int _u2 = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                _k1 = true;
                _d1= true;
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                _k1 = true;
                _d1 = false;
                break;

            case Keys.W:
                _k2 = true;
                _d2 = true;
                break;
            case Keys.S:
                _k2 = true;
                _d2 = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_k1)
            label1.Text =( _u1 = _u1 + (_d1 ? 1 : -1)).ToString();
        if (_k2)
            label2.Text = (_u2 = _u2 + (_d2 ? 1 : -1)).ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
                _k1 = false;
                _d1 = true;
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                _k1 = false;
                _d1 = false;
                break;

            case Keys.W:
                _k2 = false;
                _d2 = true;
                break;
            case Keys.S:
                _k2 = false;
                _d2 = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _k1 = false;
        _k2 = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle some key press combinations by this:

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.K) {
    //Your code here
}
```

But it requires to use some special keys pressed (like, `Alt',`Control`,`Shift` etc).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer but i don't think that will work in this case. It is supposed to controll two different "players", playing on the same keyboard. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: if you need to handle two different press which is made by different 'players' then for each player it should be handled in parallel (like by event queue)

Comment: Okay how do you make them handling paralllel to each other? I'm pretty new at coding :)

Comment: It's depends on how you work with two 'players'. But you need to have a `key press` handler to put the information about 'who pressed and what has been pressed' into some `Queue` and then you need a separated thread that will track this `Queue` and handle all pressed keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to do non-blocking work but care needs to be taken if you try to update your UI from your worker threads. You might also need to look into `Control.Invoke` if you are using WinForms.